# OWSLib and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I've got following problem:

```
>>> from owslib.wms import WebMapService
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\owslib\wms.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .etree import etree
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\owslib\etree.py", line 48, in <module>
    patch_well_known_namespaces(etree)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\owslib\etree.py", line 31, in patch_well_k
nown_namespaces
    for k, v in ns.get_namespaces().iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Installed libs:

```
---
Name: lxml
Version: 3.3.3
Location: c:\python34\lib\site-packages\lxml-3.3.3-py3.4-win32.egg
Requires:
---
Name: OWSLib
Version: 0.8.13
Location: c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, pytz
```

I'll be gratefull for any ideas how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.iteritems` was only around in Python 2.x, back when `dict.items` returned a list.  In Python 3.x however, `dict.items` was changed to return a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-view) and so `dict.iteritems` [was removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) since it was no longer necessary.

This means that the version of OWSLib that you are using was made for Python 2.x and is therefore incompatible with Python 3.x.  You need to either use Python 2.x or install a version of OWSLib that can use Python 3.x.